# MAX - MIN for each day in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am using SQL Server. I am fetching information from various tables, and I am able to do that.

In my table I have `sampletime` column which is every 30 minutes, and a value column. I want to write a query to get difference (max-min) for each day, any suggestions how I can do that?

For example:

```
SIGNAL NAME     SAMPLETIME                  VALUE
Spazio-Percorso 2014-03-06 15:01:50.3170000 219345  
Spazio-Percorso 2014-03-06 15:31:50.3260000 219384  
Spazio-Percorso 2014-03-06 16:01:50.3380000 219388  
Spazio-Percorso 2014-03-06 16:31:50.3460000 219388  
Spazio-Percorso 2014-03-06 17:01:50.3590000 219400  
Spazio-Percorso 2014-03-06 17:31:50.3690000 219434  
Spazio-Percorso 2014-03-06 18:01:50.3760000 219471
```

In this example all the rows are from the same day, what I want is to have only 1 row for each day and in the value column want to have MAX-MIN of that day

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: MSSQL management studio 2008

Comment: @Furqan And what question SQL Server? Just that you use an outdated management studio does not mean the server is also running 2 generations behind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT [SIGNAL NAME], CAST(SAMPLETIME AS DATE) AS SAMPLEDATE, MAX(VALUE)-MIN(VALUE) As Diff_Value
FROM Table1
GROUP BY CAST(SAMPLETIME AS DATE),[SIGNAL NAME]
```

Comment: Use `CAST(SAMPLETIME AS DATE)` in your select exchange of `SAMPLETIME`.

Comment: thanx for the sample, but for example if we add more rows to my example in which the sampletime is having date of 7th march , will this query give me 2 rows as a result, one for each day?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL Server 2008 or higher, you can convert your datetime column to `DATE` to get rid of the time value:

```
SELECT 
    [SIGNAL NAME], 
    CAST(SAMPLETIME AS DATE) AS SAMPLEDATE, 
    MAX(VALUE) - MIN(VALUE) AS VALUE
FROM Table1
GROUP BY [SIGNAL NAME], CAST(SAMPLETIME AS DATE)
```

Comment: Actually i dont want to have max and min values , i want to have to difference between them which is max()-Min()

Comment: This query is going to give me the maximum minus minimum for everyday? i mean as the value is always growing maximum of today is minimum of tommorrow , does it take this into account?